# how to identify whats NOT in the inner join during dataframe merge

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have one frame that looks like this (df):

```
                                 2000q1         2000q2         2000q3  
State        RegionName                                                  
New York     New York                NaN            NaN            NaN   
California   Los Angeles   207066.666667  214466.666667  220966.666667   
Illinois     Chicago       138400.000000  143633.333333  147866.666667
```

(notice that State,RegionName here is a MultiIndex)

and one frame that looks like this (ut):

```
     State    RegionName
0  Alabama        Auburn
1  Alabama      Florence
2  Alabama  Jacksonville
3  Alabama    Livingston
4  Alabama    Montevallo
```

So to get all rows where State,RegionName are in both dataframes, I do this:

```
dfut = pd.merge(df, ut, how='inner', left_index=True, right_on=['State', 'RegionName'])
```

That works.  I now want a list of rows where rows from df frame are NOT in ut frame --  like a "NOT inner join".  I am pretty sure that I need to do a LEFT join which will give me the entire df, but I am not sure how to subtract ut intersecting rows out of  it.   Hope its clear.  Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

include the parameter `indicator=True` in your `merge` and `query('_merge != "both"')`

```
dfut = pd.merge(df, ut, how='outer',
                left_index=True, right_on=['State', 'RegionName'],
                indicator=True)

dfut.query('_merge != "both"')
```

[image]

Comment: Is it the best way to do this ? Seems to be a workaround

Comment: Though I might be able to come up with a prettier solution almost 3 years later, this isn't a work around.

Comment: Does the OP want `df` minus the `inner join results` or `df full_join ut` minus the `inner join result`? Looking at the question, it seems to be the former (OP mentions `LEFT join`); the answer here seems to be for the latter but OP has accepted it as his answer. The examples OP presented doesn't help the understanding either -- even the `inner join` would be empty for those dataframes!

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler way without `query`

You want to do the inner merge of `df` and `ut` to get all the
'matching' indexes of `df` (i.e., indexes of `df` that are in `ut`)

```
inner_merge_index = pd.merge(df.reset_index(), ut, how='inner').set_index(['State', 'RegionName']).index
```

Then, you want to remove all these matched indexes from `df`

```
dfut = df.drop(list(inner_merge_index))
```

Note this also works with MultiIndex. To test it, you may want to expand your test `df` (because it has 0 intersection with `ut`) by adding a row that is actually preserved when doing the inner merge (added 'Alabama'/'Jacksonville' below). If you test it, you will see this is the only row that gets dropped.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['New York', 'New York', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
                   ['California', 'Los Angeles', '207066.666667', '214466.666667', '220966.666667'],
                   ['Illinois', 'Chicago', '138400.000000', '143633.333333', '147866.666667'],
                   ['Alabama', 'Jacksonville', '98765.000000', '54321.333333', '12345.0']],
                  columns=['State', 'RegionName', '2000q1', '2000q2', '2000q3']).set_index(['State', 'RegionName'])
```