# pandas finding inverse of merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes, one that is a list of states, cities, and a capital flag with a multiIndex of (state, city), and another that is a non-indexed (or default indexed, if that's more appropriate) list of states and their capitals, I need to perform an inner join on the two and then also find out which items in the cities df are NOT in the join.

Cities:

```
                  capital
state    city
Ohio     Akron          N
         Toledo         N
         Columbus       N
Colorado Boulder        N
         Denver         N
```

States:

```py
           state        city
0  West Virginia  Charleston
1           Ohio    Columbus
```

Inner join to find the capital of Ohio:

```py
pd.merge(cities, states, on=['state', 'city'], how='inner')
  state      city capital
0  Ohio  Columbus       N
```

Now I need to get a df that includes everything in the cities df EXCEPT Columbus, Ohio.  I've been looking at variations of `.isin()`, both with and without `reset_index()`, but I can't get it work.

Code to create the cities and states dfs.  I have `set_index()` as a separate call because if I try to do it when I create the df I get an error about `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 3), indices imply (2, 3)` and haven't figured out a way around it.

```py
cities = pd.DataFrame({'state':['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Colorado', 'Colorado'], 'city':['Akron', 'Toledo', 'Columbus', 'Boulder', 'Denver'], 'capital':['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N']}, columns=['state', 'city', 'capital'])
cities.set_index(('state', 'city'))
states = pd.DataFrame({'state':['West Virginia', 'Ohio'], 'city':['Charleston', 'Columbus']})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to identify whats NOT in the inner join during dataframe merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518639/how-to-identify-whats-not-in-the-inner-join-during-dataframe-merge)

Comment: or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242368/anti-merge-in-pandas-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `how='outer'` and `indicator='source'`, and the keep only those that are `'left_only'`:

```
merge = cities.merge(states, on=['state', 'city'], how='outer', indicator='source')
result = merge[merge.source.eq('left_only')].drop('source', axis=1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
      state     city capital
0      Ohio    Akron       N
1      Ohio   Toledo       N
3  Colorado  Boulder       N
4  Colorado   Denver       N
```

As an alternative you could use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), in the following way:

```
mask = ~cities.reset_index().city.isin(states.city)
print(cities[pd.Series(data=mask.values, index=cities.index)])
```

**Output**

```
                 capital
state    city           
Ohio     Akron         N
         Toledo        N
Colorado Boulder       N
         Denver        N
```

The idea of the second approach is to create a boolean mask with an index matching the one in `cities`. A variation on the second approach is the following:

```
# drop the index
re_indexed = cities.reset_index()

# find the mask
mask = ~re_indexed.city.isin(states.city)

# reindex back
result = re_indexed[mask].set_index(['state', 'city'])

print(result)
```

Comment: I got flagged as a duplicate; the suggested solutions were the same as your first one using `indicator`, but I really like the use of `isin()` in the second method, which I didn't see in the others.

Comment: @jml Glad I could help!